# How to conver a row to multiple rows with the same index

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I have a table like the following.
[image]

And i want to convert it to something like this
[image]

I tried to find the solution online but i didn't found anything related to my issues.
Is there a excel or powerquery solution for this?

Comment: The search term you couldn't find is **unpivot**.  Pretty simple in PQ. Just select the Index column and Unpivot other columns

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/72433244/9199828