# i want to put all column for 1 row into row in xls

Tags: excel

i want to put all column for 1 row into row in xls

input:
[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: C1 to C5 is not fixed its variant  for each table .......

Comment: Search this forum for "unpivot"  Plenty of examples as to how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Not the cleanest way but it does the job.

[image]

Formula in column I:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$4;ROUNDUP(ROW()/5;0))
```

Notice the division between row number and 5. The divisor is 5 because you got 5 elements to get (c1,c2,c3,c4,c5). Change 5 to whatever columns you need to fecht.

Also, please notice you need to drag manually until you get the quantity of elements. In this case, your data is a table of 4x5 = 20 so you need to manually drag the formula from row 1 to row 20

Formula in column J:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$F$4;MATCH(I1;$A$1:$A$4;0);COUNTIF($I$1:I1;I1))
```

Comment: C1 to C5 is not fixed its variant  for each table .......tbl1 c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7
tbl2 c1 c2 c3    
tbl3 c1 c2 c3 c4 c5  
tbl4 c1 c2     
Outputtbl1 c1
tbl1 c2
tbl1 c3
tbl1 c4
tbl1 c5
tbl1 c6
tbl1 c7
tbl2 c1
tbl2 c2
tbl2 c3
tbl3 c1
tbl3 c2
tbl3 c3
tbl3 c4
tbl3 c5
tbl4 c1
tbl4 c2

Comment: @GouravNagar Please, next time add a **real** data example so you can get the solution you need. Anyways, this answer will return 0/blanks even if the size is different. You just need to filter those rows and delete them. It takes literally seconds

Answer (score 0):

1. Select your data
2. Data -> from Table/Range (unselect "My Data has headers")
   (=> Power Query Editor is started)
3. Select Column 2 to Column 6 in Power Query Editor
4. Transform -> Unpivot Columns
5. Home -> Close and Load to ... (Existing Worksheet "H1")

DONE! ;-)

**Screenshot step 2:**
[image]

**Screenshot step 3+4:**
[image]

**result:**
[image]